# JavaScript regular expression having a weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, behavior

I'm currently making a scripting language for a Discord bot I'm maintaining and I'm facing a weird issue. The following code takes a string as input (`I think {if:3|=|0|you are|TechRax is} {range:1|100}`), uses the `match` method of the string to get all functions (expression: `/\{(.*?):(.*?)\}/g`) from the string. Then using a `forEach`, I process all of these matches then I replace the matched content with the result on the string, using the `replace` method.

Here is the code I use:

```
let newString = 'I think {if:3|=|0|you are|TechRax is} {range:1|100}';
const functionPattern = /\{(.*?):(.*?)\}/g;
const foundFunctions = newString.match(functionPattern);
if (!foundFunctions) throw new Error('No function found');

foundFunctions.forEach((fn) => {
  const parsedInput = functionPattern.exec(fn); // = null once the second iteration begins... ? only the first one work. Same issue if I invert the function orders (first works, second and + no)
  if (!parsedInput || !parsedInput[1] || !parsedInput[2]) return;

  try {
    /*const customFunction = new (require(`../../Production/Tags/${parsedInput[1]}`))(this.client, context, contextType);
    if (!customFunction) return;

    const result = customFunction.run(parsedInput[2].split('|'));*/
    const result = 'Stack Overflow test';
    newString = newString.replace(fn, result);
  } catch (e) {
    newString = newString.replace(fn, e);
  }
});

// Print newString here (depends if you're on browser or node)
```

In this context, `this.client.constants.functionPattern = /\{(.*?):(.*?)\}/g`, `foundFunctions = ['{if:4|=|0|you are|alien is}', '{range:1|100}']` and `newString = 'I think {if:{argslen}|=|0|you are|{args} is} {range:1|100}'`.

Now let's start describing the behaviour, the **first iteration** goes well: the function module gets imported, it gets processed and the final content gets replaced on the string.

The problem concerns the **second** one (and all others), the `exec` method of the function expression returns `null`. I do not understand this at all, first I thought it was a kind of bug with my RegExp, maybe `{random:1|100}` was not matching but no because it works perfectly on Regexr.com and... the weirdest: if I eval it (`/\{(.*?):(.*?)\}/g.exec('{range:1|100}`), it doesn't return `null` but the actual result I expect.

I guess I'm wrong somewhere but after passing some hours on it I still do not get why it isn't working.
I hope you'll be able to help me out, thanks!
If you need any complementary information, I'm here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  (how to make a *complete* code example)  (in other words make this a reproducible code snippet)

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're defining your regex `GLOBAL`

- but don't reset the internal pointer inside of the loop: `myRegex.lastIndex = 0;` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex))
- alternatively, you could recreate a regex inside of the forEach.

```js
let newString = 'I think {if:3|=|0|you are|TechRax is} {range:1|100}';
let functionPattern = /\{([^}]*):([^}]*)\}/g;
const foundFunctions = newString.match(functionPattern);
if (!foundFunctions)
 throw new Error('No function found');

foundFunctions.forEach(fn => {
  //const functionPattern = /\{([^}]*):([^}]*)\}/g; // or redeclare
  const parsedInput = functionPattern.exec(fn);
  if (!parsedInput || !parsedInput[1] || !parsedInput[2]) return;

  try {
    const result = 'Stack Overflow test';
    newString = newString.replace(fn, result);
    functionPattern.lastIndex = 0;  // reset internal pointer of your regex
  } catch (e) {
    newString = newString.replace(fn, e);
  }
});
console.log(newString);
```

I almost forgot: I suggest a more robust regex pattern: [`\{(\[^}\]*):(\[^}\]*)\}`](https://regex101.com/r/0wNbBS/1)
However, your pattern seems to be good enough.

Comment: It's working well! Thank you, I did not think looking at these properties. Thanks also for the pattern suggestion I'll look into it ;)

Comment: Good Answer! But I'd love if the concept of `lastIndex` was highlighted a bit prominetly. Here is the link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex